# Prevent double function calling by parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, unique

I have a loop in my Node.js application which is continuously fetching "unprocessed" rows from my database (1 request per second).

Each row I receive from the DB will call a function with a unique numeric ID and the other details from the DB as parameters. As soon as the data was processed inside this function the DB is updated and the row is marked as "processed".

```
function fetch() {
  db.query("SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE processed=0 ORDER BY id ASC", function(err, results) {
    if(results.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            process(results[i].id, results[i].data);
    }
  });
}
var interval_fetch = setInterval(fetch, 1000);

function process(id, data) {
  // Process data
  db.query("UPDATE table SET processed=1 WHERE id="+id);
}
```

However, in some cases it takes more than a second process the data and to update the DB. In this cases process() it called two or even more times with the same parameters.

What is the easiest way in Node.js environment to ensure the function is only called once at the same time with a certain ID parameter?

Are there any packages that offer this functionality and require only two or three lines of extra code?

(The solution does not necessarily have to prevent from calling the function multiple times. If I was able to check inside process(), if it was already called with a certain id, I could end it there as well before the data is processed twice.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I ended up with a relatively simple solution. Therefore I am answering my own question.

I just maintain an object containing all IDs that are currently processed and not updated in the DB yet. Each time process() is called, I check if the ID is currently in progress and cancel if applicable, before the data will be processed twice.

```
var in_progress = {}; // Object that contains the IDs

function fetch() {
  db.query("SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE processed=0 ORDER BY id ASC", function(err, results) {
    if(results.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            process(results[i].id, results[i].data);
    }
  });
}
var interval_fetch = setInterval(fetch, 1000);

function process(id, data) {
  if(in_progress.hasOwnProperty(id)) { // Check if ID is in progress
    console.log("ID "+id+" in progress - do nothing");
    return;
  } else {
    in_progress[id] = true; // Insert ID into object

    // Process data here, then run below query

    db.query("UPDATE table SET processed=1 WHERE id="+id, function() {
      // Remove ID from object once DB is updated - Timeout to make sure nothing can overlap with the fetch function
      setTimeout(function(){ delete in_progress[id]; }, 1000); 
    });
  }
}
```

This works exactly as I want. I can even make a much faster fetch interval, to start to process all new data from my DB without noticeable delay. Still nothing will ever be processed twice.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any packages that offer this functionality and require only two or three lines of extra code?

Yes: https://github.com/isaacs/once

Also, all promise libraries should offer this out of the box. And generators.

But instead of using them, I suggest to change the way you code. setTimeout instead of setInterval can eliminate the whole issue this way:

```
function fetch() {
  db.query("SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE processed=0 ORDER BY id ASC", function(err, results) {
    if(results.length > 0) {
       for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
          process(results[i].id, results[i].data)
    }
    setTimeout(fetch, 1000)
  })
}
var interval_fetch = setTimeout(fetch, 1000)

function process(id, data) {
  // Process data
  db.query("UPDATE table SET processed=1 WHERE id="+id)
}
```

Comment: I believe the intent of the `setInterval` is because he wants the job to repeat every second, not because he only wants it to occur once.

Comment: that's why I added a recursive `setTimeout` call there

Comment: I appreciate your reply. The package partially does what I want, but the setTimeout suggestion not. Please see my own answser.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified, set the timeout after the job is complete.

```
function fetch() {
  db.query("SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE processed=0 ORDER BY id ASC", function(err, results) {
    if(results.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            process(results[i].id, results[i].data);
    }
  });
}
setTimeout(fetch, 1000);

function process(id, data) {
  // Process data
  db.query("UPDATE table SET processed=1 WHERE id="+id, function() {
    setTimeout(fetch, 1000);
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work as I would like to. If the query returns multiple rows with different data, process() is called mutiple times with different parameters. Each one will set a new timeout once completed. If one function call is finished after 0.1 seconds and another after 5 seconds, the slow one will be processed again.